# jQuery plugin to create website tours on Dynamic pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, linkedin-api

I have tried a LinkedIn Hopscotch and Intro.js to create Website tours. But both of them works perfectly well for static page/ multiple static pages.

The problem is that I have a single page application - where most of the elements are dynamically created with the help of BackboneJS. In such cases - both Hopscotch and Intro.js cannot attach/wait for dynamically created elements.

Is there any library that can do so. Or if that can be achieved using Hopscotch/Intro.js

```
var tour = {
    id: "hello",
    steps: [{
            title: "Welcome!",
            content: "Hey there! If you have just 2 minutes.",
            target: document.querySelector(".list a"),
            placement: "bottom"
        }, {
            title: "Create a new file",
            content: "Create a new file",
            target: document.querySelector("#page a"),
            placement: "right",
            onNext: function () {
                $('.add-new a').click();
            }
            ]
    };
    hopscotch.startTour(tour);
```

For ex: above in Hopscotch what should I do after $('.add-new a').click(); which opens a modal window?

Answer (score 5):

[**Sideshow**](http://fortesinformatica.github.io/Sideshow) is a modern and powerful library for creating interactive tours for web applications and sites, and is perfect for SPA applications.

More than just guiding your users, Sideshow can interact with them:

- Highlight the part you're talking about in each step (a form, div, image, field, and so forth), by masking the rest of the screen (Sideshow doesn't use the z-index approach for this, its mask isn't positionated behind the element, but really surrounds it).
- Monitor your user's behavior and the state of some screen.
- Create smart steps for your tutorials, which proceeds automatically when some condition is satisfied
- Create relationships between your tutorials, this way, when your user finishes some tutorial, a list with the related tours is shown.
- Use Markdown for rich formatting a step description
- Use events (e.g. beforeStep/afterStep, beforeWizardStarts/afterWizardEnds) to perform some preparation or anything else
- Show contextual tutorials according to the screen being viewed by your user, each tutorial has its own conditions to check if it's eligible for that screen or not

**And other powerful features!**

Comment: Amazing library! I was looking for one similiar and this is really great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try to initialize hopscotch only after everything is loaded from backbone like this:

```
render: function() {
    // do your normal render stuff
    this.afterRender();
},

afterRender: function() {
    hopscotch.startTour(tour);
}
```